# Moving TKinter Window.destroy to a function from a button, not so simple?

Tags: python

I'm giving myself a crash-course in Python and TKinter, but there is one small detail I can't grasp.
Closing a Toplevel window in a function instead of a button.

My button alone works perfect:

```
button = Button(UpdateWindow, text="Destroy Window", command=UpdateWindow.destroy)
```

Using a button with a reference to a close function bombs:

```
def Close():
    tkMessageBox.showwarning('', 'Close function called', icon="warning")
    command=UpdateWindow.destroy

btn_updatecon = Button(ContactForm, text="Update", width=20, command=lambda:[UpdateData(), Close()])
```

What am I missing in the function?  It is being called, but no close.

The SQLite3 project im working with is [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H60lk0W6GTa0x7lfhIoslO8W8w5HBOlT)

Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: `command=UpdateWindow.destroy`, as a statement, is utterly pointless - you assign a method (without actually calling it) to a local variable which will immediately cease to exist.  You want `UpdateWindow.destroy()`.

Comment: omg I'm embarrassed.
Thank you Jason.  Worked perfect of course.

Answer (score 0):

`command=UpdateWindow.destroy` defines a variable. If you want to keep the command variable use `command()`, while if you want the recommended way use `UpdateWindow.destroy()`